# ¿Cómo leer url de un json (de google spreadsheets) en javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo una url que está enlazada a un `json` de google spreadsheets. Necesito encontrar la forma de leer esos datos y mostrarlos en una página `html`

Comment: ¿Es un spreadsheet público? ¿Se puede acceder a la URL desde cualquier navegador sin loguearse antes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para leer desde una URL pública y meter el contenido del JSON en una página (por ahora sin formato) se puede usar:

```js
dondeMostrar.textContent = 'Trayendo los datos...';

var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
httpRequest.open('GET', 'https://api.github.com/users/codenautas', true);
httpRequest.send(null);

httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (httpRequest.readyState === 4 /*Listo*/) {
    if (httpRequest.status === 200 /*Ok*/) {
      dondeMostrar.textContent = httpRequest.responseText;
    } else {
      dondeMostrar.textContent = 'error';
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<pre id=dondeMostrar>
</pre>
```

Para el ejemplo uso una URL https://api.github.com/users/codenautas pública que contiene un JSON.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el código @EmilioPlatzer, me ha servido de mucho.